# USB blocking using minifilter driver (passThrough)

Tags: c, windows, device-driver, usb-flash-drive

I am writing a mini-filter code for USB (Flash Drives) for blocking i.e (Access Denied).So, could someone help me out,  how to detect or block USB or what methods to use in passThrough WDK sample code for ***USB detection and USB blocking***?

I am trying to use *IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY in PFLT_INSTANCE_SETUP_CALLBACK*. Am i on right path?? if yes then how to use IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY in PFLT_INSTANCE_SETUP_CALLBACK???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 3 months of work I have finally achieved blocking.
Though I can't give direct code here. 
But following link might help.

[PassThrough Development](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wdk/thread/692509d6-99ac-450e-abec-7aea61a751c5)

[GitHub Link](https://github.com/surajfale/passthrough-minifilter-driver)

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to get the device object using `FltGetDiskDeviceObject` and then check for `FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA` flag in `device_object->Characteristics`. Once you get to know about the device type, then you can block or allow the required operations (that you need to register with `FLT_OPERATION_REGISTRATION`).

Comment: ya i have tried it. But it won't work. Can you explain me in detail, probably with a code?

Comment: Is there any other way like bu using FltCreateFile method? Because i know that it can be used to block access to files. But i don't know for a Volume?